# how to sort an NSArray of float values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an NSArray  like this:

how to sort NSarray float with value like this:122.00,45.00,21.01,5.90

Comment: How do u store floats in a NSArray?

Comment: btw: Your floats are ordered — descending.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[@Ron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610379/how-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-float-values/7610588#7610588) is perfect, but I want to add sorting by using an comparator block. For this trivial case it might be overkill, but it is very handy when it comes to sorting of objects in respect to several properties

```
NSArray *myArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:45.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:122.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:21.01], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.9], nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 floatValue] > [obj2 floatValue])
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if ([obj1 floatValue] < [obj2 floatValue])
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Answer (score 11):

try this it work for me

```
NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.01],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:13.01],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.01],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.01],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.5],nil];
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here... use `NSSortDescriptor`

First Convert the float values into `NSNumber`

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"floatValue"
                                              ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i tried it but it can't work. NSNumber not tried ,thanks for reply

Comment: have u changed float to NSNumber?

Comment: Indeed this won't work. NSNumber isn't key value coding compliant to @"floats". try @"floatValue" instead.