# how to sort array in descending oder in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I had a array  how to sort this in descending oder 
below is the array I need to sort How can I do this ? and below is the code I written

```
array(
"4.3",
"4.8",
"4.4",
"4.8",
"6.5"
) 


  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
  sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"floats" ascending:YES];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
  [sortArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
  NSLog(@"sort array %@",sortArray);
```

Comment: You need to convert float to NSNumbe first. then you can apply compare with sortedArrayUsingComparator.[Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610379/how-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-float-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `NO` to `ascending` parameter:

`sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"floats" ascending:NO];`

Answer (score 2):

Just try below code.

```
NSArray *arForData = @[@4.3,@4.8,@4.4,@4.8,@6.5];
NSArray *sortedArray = [arForData  sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                            ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
                                //descending order
                                return [obj2 compare:obj1];
                                //ascending order
                                return [obj1 compare:obj2];
                            }];
NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Result- descending
(
    "6.5",
    "4.8",
    "4.8",
    "4.4",
    "4.3"
)

Result- ascending
(
    "4.3",
    "4.4",
    "4.8",
    "4.8",
    "6.5"
)

Comment: sortedArrayUsingComparator is the absolutely most flexible and at the same time most efficient way to sort arrays. Since you write the code, it can sort in _any_ way you like.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@4.3,@4.8,@4.4,@4.8,@6.5,nil];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"floats" ascending:NO];
NSMutableArray *sortArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:arr];
[sortArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
NSLog(@"sort array %@",sortArray);
```

Comment: give only one answer if you want multiple suggestion then please update this answer.