# sorting increasingly an array of objects by its CGFloat value

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I am receiving an array of object in the function below, each item in that array contains a value, which is type of CGFloat, I am using this function below, but getting an error at the return line : "Expected identifier"

```
- (void)setupPieChartWithItems:(NSArray *)items {

    NSArray *sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        CGFloat first = [(PNPieChartDataItem*)a value];
        CGFloat second = [(PNPieChartDataItem*)b value];
        return [first > second];
    }];
}
```

Where is the error? Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286901/sorting-an-array-of-object-with-respect-to-the-float-value ? `[first > second]` first is like asking a method named `>` on two objects `first` and `second` but they aren't objects, they are primitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue may be with the  brackets  in this  `[first > second];`  as `sortedArrayUsingComparator` is  required to return NSComparisonResult value not array of bool value

replace your code with

```
- (void)setupPieChartWithItems:(NSArray *)items {

    NSArray *sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        CGFloat first = [(PNPieChartDataItem*)a value];
        CGFloat second = [(PNPieChartDataItem*)b value];
        return [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:first] compare:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:second]];

     }];
}
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: The block returns a `BOOL` instead of a `NSComparisonResult`.

Comment: @Willeke Ohh Don't feel bad , I updated my answer and it is better than yours now you would you upvote ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code for sorting with this one :

```
NSSortDescriptor *highestToLowest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = items.mutableCopy;
[sortedArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highestToLowest]];
```

Setting `YES` to `ascending` will result in 1.3, 2.6, 3.1… whereas setting `NO` will result in 3.1, 2.6, 1.3…

Tell me if you need any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from `[first > second]` to fix the compiler error, and the block must return a `NSComparisonResult`:

```
- (void)setupPieChartWithItems:(NSArray *)items {
    NSArray *sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(PNPieChartDataItem *a, PNPieChartDataItem *b) {
        CGFloat first = [a value];
        CGFloat second = [b value];
        if (first > second)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        if (first < second)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
}
```

Like in this answer [how to sort an NSArray of float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7611008/4244136).